# PyQt5 How to Call a Function in Main Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How will I call the ShowUsers function in my main function?

```
 def ShowUsers(self):
    with open("accounts.txt", "r") as f:

        data = f.readlines()

        for line in data:
            lineZ = line.strip().split(";")
            a = lineZ[0]
            self.ComList.addItem(a)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i'm new in pyqt and python. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I see in your code `ShowUsers` belongs to a class, let's call it `class1`

```
class class1:
   def __init__(self, {your parameters}):
       {some code}

   def ShowUsers(self):
       {your code}
```

To use that method (considering that it is not a static method) you must create an object and use it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    {some code}
    my_object = class1({your parameters})
    my_object.ShowUsers()
    {some another code}
```

Note: *this answer is not only for pyqt, but for python*

Comment: that make's a lot of sense :) thank you very much!